# Imagemagick not creating correct color

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

So I when I rung this command:

```
convert -size 32x32 xc:transparent -fill "#ff0000" \
        -draw "circle 15,16 8,10" png32:"/Users/rzec/test test.png"
```

a round circle is created however the color is not `FF0000` but it is `#FC0F1D`.  Is there any reason this would happen?

Interestingly, if I use `FFFFFF` that is the color that is generated.

I am running Mac OS X 10.9 and ImageMagick 6.8.7-7 Q16 x86_64 2013-11-27

Comment: It works for me, running V6.8.9-1 on OSX. I tested like this: `convert a.png -colorspace rgb -colors 256 -depth 8 txt: | egrep -v "#FF0000|#000000"` and found no pixels that were neither red nor black.

Comment: Interesting, I guess there is something weird with color picking when viewing the image in OSX preview.  When I use my color picker in that application, I get FC0F1D but when I load the image into Chrome and use my color picker, I get FF0000 as expected.  looking at the actually content of the file you did showed me the color was in fact FF0000.  Thanks.